# Using PasswordHasher in Asp.net Mvc6, Identity 3.0

Tags: asp.net, hash, asp.net-identity

I've working on learning Asp.net, but I'm having troubles with the password hasher.

I want to use the non-modified version of the thing, but I'm severely lacking on instructions. Googling has failed me.

So it's a very very general question.
Would some one be so kind to provide a small tutorial on password hashing during User registration and login.

I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Password hashing should be handled for you out of the box. Is there a concrete issue you are having?

Comment: No, no particular issue.
Just wanted an example of using Password Hasher on it's own.